# can I make image get focus using className

Tags: javascript, html

I want to `focus` on image link by javascript, the problem is that I don't have direct access to my image.

```html
<li classe="product-1">
  <div classe="shop">
    <a class="img-link" src="xxxxxx">
      <img class="image1">
    </a>
  </div>
</li>
```

i tried using access to give focus to the image but doesn't work

```js
var imaglink = document.getElementsByClassName("product-1")[0].getElementsByClassName("shop")[0].getElementsByClassName("img-link")[0];
imagelink.focus();
```

if anyone have any suggestion ho to resolve this probleme i will be thankful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const img = document.querySelector("li a > img")
img.focus()
```

or

```
const img = document.querySelector(".shop > a img")
```

or if there multiple images

```
const img = document.querySelectorAll(".product-1 img")[0]
```

Comment: yup querySelectorAll is the good solution its works well thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Possible typo, depending on language I think... I notice in your code you have some lines with classe="..." other times class="..."

with your li element have classe, that might be returning an undefined value, so the rest of your selection isn't going to work.

Comment: yes there is a typing error here, but i only made it here when i was typing the code here, and there is any typo in my website. thankyou for your remarks

Answer (score 1):

You can just combine the selectors together and use `querySelector` like

```
document.querySelector(".product-1 .shop .img-link").focus();
```

```js
document.querySelector(".product-1 .shop .img-link").focus();
```

```css
a:focus{
  display:inline-block;
  border:20px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<li class="product-1">
  <div class="shop">
    <a href class="img-link">
      <img class="image1" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
    </a>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: thank you so much. this is exactly what i was looking for, I'm really grateful to you